# Save all data into variable tcl

Tags: linux, unix, while-loop, tcl

I have a code which i want to use to open a log file, extract the contents and save it into a variable so i can extract the data from the variable in the future. How do i do that? So far the code saves only the last data of the log file into the variable. I think the while loop grabs data line by line and the variable stores it one by one and overwrites the previous data as it progresses, how do i change the code so that it stores all the data as the code progresses?

```
set fp [open "filename.log" r]
while { [gets $fp data] >= 0 } { 
    set written $data
}
close $fp 
puts $written
```

please help

Comment: What kind of data structure do you want to use to store the data? In a list with one line per element? Does each line need to split into separate fields? Please think about your requirements and update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this with `append` command:

```
set written ""
set fp [open "filename.log" r]
while { [gets $fp data] >= 0 } { 
    # append last data read
    append written $data
    # add some line feed for readability (may not be necessary)
    append written "\n"
}
close $fp 
puts $written
```

Answer (score 4):

You might as well use [`read`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/read.htm) instead of using `while` and `gets`:

```
set fp [open "filename.log" r]
set written [read $fp]
close $fp 
puts $written
```

Answer (score 1):

After good answer of @purplepsycho and @Jerry, You can use `fileutil::cat` function which even not requires to `open` and `close` the file descriptor and syntax is,

```
package require fileutil
set var [fileutil::cat "filename.log"]
puts $var
```